# Was this person really dead in Doctor Sleep?

Tags: doctor-sleep

We know Danny is plagued by visions and dreams and at one point in the movie

> he wakes up to see the dead bodies of his one night stand and her baby

Did they actually die? Or was this just a scary vision Danny had. Evidence from the book would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in the movie he only gets these visits from dead people, so...